# Having VS Online build use packages folder from source control possible?

Tags: git, msbuild, nuget, azure-devops

I'm trying to use automated builds with Visual Studio Online.
However, some of my nuget packages is from a local server on our LAN, but I've added the packages folder to source control (git repo).
Is it possible to tell the build host that "don't try to restore, you've got the packages, go ahead and use them!"?

-

Edit: Never mind on my part. We've moved our private nuget server to the cloud "long ago".

Comment: I don't think you can do this with the hosted build controller, only an on-premises one.

Comment: So it's not at all possible not to use package restore, but have msbuild just reference packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this work in a hosted build controller.  The package restore step will throw a warning saying that it couldn't restore the package(s) in question, but msbuild will still pass as long as hint paths are correct.  Pretty lame, but it works.

Another solution (I don't know if this is better or not) is to use the old school .nuget folder references from your solution.  You would need to add a packagesources block in nuget.targets for your nonstandard feed.  Also pretty lame, but it works.

Comment: I forgot this question since we moved the server to the cloud long ago, but thanks for you answer. :) Tagging as answer as it probably is.